# Summary effect size of multiple dependent effect sizes

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size

**Problem Statement**

I am currently conducting a meta-analysis. At the moment, I am just calculating the effect size for each included study (for our purpose we chose the correlation coefficient r). However, as I don't want to include multiple effect sizes for a single study, I need to compute a summary effect size in some cases. Since effect sizes from the same population are not independent, one cannot just take the arithmetic mean of the variance, but instead must consider the intercorrelation among the individual effect sizes (see: Borenstein, Hedges, Higgins, & Rothstein, 2011).

In the case of two effect sizes, the calculations are pretty straightforward (where: Y = effect size, V = variance of effect size Y, r = correlation between Y1 and Y2):

$
\overline{Y}=\frac{1}{2}\left(Y_{1}+Y_{2}\right)
$

$
V_{\overline{Y}}=\frac{1}{4}\left(V_{Y_{1}}+V_{Y_{2}}+2 r \sqrt{V_{Y_{1}}} \sqrt{V_{Y_{2}}}\right)
$

**Question**

I am unsure how to calculate a summary effect size of more than two effect sizes. For instance, a study reports the following correlation matrix:

[image: example correlation matrix]

The highlighted numbers are the correlations of interest (i.e., correlations between physical abuse and CU traits; verbal abuse and CU traits; sexual abuse and CU traits; and emotional abuse and CU traits). BUT, I only want one effect size for: Abuse and CU traits. Hence, I need to calculate a summary effect size.

Any help or references that explain the calculation of summary effect sizes is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Matthias